# If $f$ is bijective then $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that if $f$ is bijective then $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$.

My attempt: $y\in f(A^c) \iff y = f(x)$ where $x\in A^c \iff y = f(x)$ where $x\notin A \iff y \notin f(A)\iff y\in f(A)^c$.

Is this correct (note that $A^c$ is the complement of $A$)?

Comment: It looks fine, note that bijectivity is used when you say $y \notin f(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. In fact, you use the fact that $f$ is injective when you say that $y=f(x)$ where $x \notin A$ implies $y \notin f(A)$. On the other hand, you use surjectivity to reverse the previous claim.

Answer (score 2):

Figuratively speaking, if there are $10$ marks to rate I will rate the work as $8$. (This is just figurative, not to pretend I am a rater being preachy :)).

The problem is the statement "$y = f(x)$ where $x \notin A$ iff $y \notin f(A)$". It seems that the author might smuggle the "iff" here; he may or may not be completely sure about what is happening here. To remedy this you have to learn to use the quantifiers accurately! Note that by the bijectivity assumption of $f$ what we really have is "$y = f(x)$ for **exactly one** $x \notin A$ iff $y \notin f(A)$". Note that without the help of "exactly one" from bijectivity we cannot be sure about this passage.